# Very basic: syntax of classes and objects

Tags: c#

I feel like this should have been explained on page 1 of lesson 1 somewhere, but either it wasn't or I missed it.

If there is the following class:

```
class Person
{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public int age {get; set;}
}
```

Then later I do this:

```
Person myUncle = new Person();
```

Why do I need that first Person at the start?

I know I am creating a new object of type "Person" that is called "myUncle".

Why do we have that Person at the start?  Could a new Person(); object be something else?

Every tutorial / book whatever I have seen just rolls right through this part with the author saying "ok now we make a new instance this way..." but never explains why the syntax is like this.

Comment: That's just how it is.

Comment: Long story short, C# requires that all variable to be typed , that's why you specify the type of the variable at declaration. the _var_ keyword is syntactic sugar i.e the compiler replaces 'var' with the actual type. But 'myUncle' will always be a Person or a subclass of Person

Answer (score 6):

The left side declares a variable of type `Person`.

The right side creates an object of type `Person`.

The `=` assigns the object on the right the variable on the left.

You might ask, why can't `C#` figure out what variable type I want?
The answer is, it can:

```
var myUncle = new Person();
```

However, there are situations where you might want to declare the type explicitly.
This is a slightly contrived example, but suppose I had a new class which is a subclass of `Person`.

```
class Child : Person
{ 
    public bool isChildish {get; set;}
}
```

I might could then declare a variable of type `Person` to hold an object of type `Child`.

```
Person myUncle = new Child();
```

Now, the `Person` on the left looks less redundant.

**Update**: One reason why you might want `Person myUncle` over `var myUncle` is because you can separate declaration from initialization.

The following code will compile:

```
Person myUncle;
myUncle = new Person();
```

The following code will not compile;

```
var myUncle;
myUncle = new Person();
```

Comment: So functionally there is no difference between var myUncle and Person myUncle, and the only reason to do one and not the other is..? For readability?

Comment: Yes, there is no functional difference in this case. I consider it a matter of preference. People who come from languages like C sometimes prefer their types to be explicit.

Comment: @user3565424, Note however, that you cannot declare `var myUncle;` on a line by itself, but you can easily declare `Person myUncle;` on a line by itself. This is an important distinction which may become more important if you need to separate declaration from assignment.

Answer (score 3):

A way I like to think about it is like this: The right hand side is what the object "actually is" and the left hand side, is what you will be "telling" other parts of your application the object is. So in the basic example like yours, you are creating a Person and telling the rest of your application that this is a Person object, but you don't always have to reveal exactly what your object is. For example:

```
Person p1 = new Doctor();
Person p2 = new Teacher();
IService s = new ServiceImpl();
IEnumerable<Person> personEnum = new List<Person>();
```

In the first two examples you are creating two objects doctor and teacher which inherit from Person, but any part of your application that is passed p1 or p2 will only know it is a Person object. In the third example, the object is actually of type ServiceImpl, but the rest of your application will only know that this is an object that implements the IService interface.

The point of all of this is to keep your application loosely coupled, by only revealing as much as you need to about the actual objects.